# Logstash conversion from float to scientific

Tags: logstash

I have an element in a CSV file that has a value of 0.022222222. Naturally, this hits the float data type limitation. However, logstash is converting it to the scientific notation.

I want the value in Elasticsearch to be float and not string. How can I achieve that?

Logstash and ES 7.1.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
 mutate {
      convert => {
          "fieldname" => "float"
      }
    }
```

Comment: I already did that. However, if my value is too long it converts to scientific notation.  That's why the original question